# Object not shown after applying transformation functions in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, transformation

I want to draw a garden of flowers using opengl transformation objects. At first I have started drawing petal of flower and I want it to be rotated so the flower will be created, but when I use `glRotatef()` I can't see the object anymore.
Here's part of my code:

```
const float DEG2RAD = 3.14159 / 180;

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 400.0, 0.0, 400.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void petal(void)
{
    float x, y, z;
    float A = 20;
    float t;

    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glPointSize(2);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(90.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
    glTranslatef(10,10, 0);

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    t = 0;
    while (t < 90)
    {
        x = A*sin(2 * t*DEG2RAD)*cos(t*DEG2RAD);
        y = A*sin(2 * t*DEG2RAD)*sin(t*DEG2RAD);
        z = 0;
        glVertex3f(x, y, z);
        t++;
    }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
int main(void)
{
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Garden");
    init();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glutDisplayFunc(petal);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IIRC you have to call the matrix functions in the *reverse* order of the transformations (so the transformations are applied bottom-to-top). What you have now, if you uncomment `glRotatef`, is a translation to (100, 100) followed by a rotation around the center of the world. Also, if you want to rotate inside the 2D plane, `glRotatef`'s axis must be along the z coordinate, not x.

Comment: @Quentin Correct, the last function will be applied first, but when I uncomment  `glRotatef` i cant see anything anymore, i think it gets out of viewport and i dont know what should be the values of transformation?

Comment: Did you try fixing the axis ? If you have used an orthographic projection with the origin in one corner, I suspect the object is getting rotated out of the view.

Comment: @Quentin you mean like this : `glRotatef(90.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5); glTranslatef(10,10, 0);` 
do u know if i should use matrix, i mean finding the values of each matrices and then multiply them?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. In the old OpenGL API you're using, the matrix stack handles matrix multiplication by itself. The "modern" API does require you to make the computations by yourself. As for your question, I'm sorry but I have no further suggestions -- you should post your full code in case the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @Quentin OK thanks :)) I've updated the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to compile and test your full code. The error lies in the order of the transformations in `petal`:

```
glRotatef(90.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
glTranslatef(100,100, 0);
```

This will first translate the petal towards the center of the window, then rotate it 90° around the bottom-left corner (the origin set by `gluOrtho2D`). As a result, the petal goes outside the window. You simply need to swap both calls:

```
glTranslatef(100,100, 0);
glRotatef(90.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Then the petal is first rotated around the origin (which is its tip), *then* translated to the center.

As a side note, it looks like you forgot to call `glutInit(&argc, argv)` before using GLUT, I have had a hard error at runtime about that.

Comment: Also note the 0.5 became 1.0 in glRotatef. You most likely want your axis to be a unity vector.

Comment: @Quentin Yeah:) One thing more, i want to create a flower with 4 petals so i want to have both the first object before transformation and after that. do u know how can i do it?

Comment: @3ngineer The most straightforward way is to just give each one its own transform matrix, by calling the whole `petal` function several times with a parameter for the petal angle. You should avoid `glFlush` when doing that though.

Comment: @Quentin would u plz tell me how can i call this function, i've coded some but none worked, i've aslo used `glpushmatrix` and `glpopmatrix`. 
After using function 2 times nothing shown in window.

Comment: @3ngineer Something like [this](http://pastebin.com/WvxJhL9z), quite simply using a loop to display five petals with varying angles.